# Ionic Cordova In App Purchase - Fail

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase, ionic3

My Ionic 3 application is working great, except the in-app purchase. I am using the native cordova notifications plugin ([link here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase/)). I am not the best at stepping through my code when working with other apis as I really need to start practicing.

No errors occur when building the application, and no error occurs when I click the button. I am simply clueless.

this.purchaseId = 'my.sku.that.is.active.in.the.ios.and.android.appstore'

Code:

```
buyButton() {

this.iap.buy(this.purchaseId)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
    localStorage.setItem("premium", "1");
    this.premiumUser = true;

    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: "You are now a premium user. Congradulations and thank you for contributing.",
      showCloseButton: true,
      closeButtonText: "Welcome"
    });
    toast.present();
  }).catch((err) => {
    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: err + "",
      showCloseButton: true,
      closeButtonText: "OK"
    });
    toast.present();
  });

}
```

No purchase box appears, and no error occurs. Perhaps someone might know the fix? You would be very very appreciated.

The catch statement returns '[Object object]' in a toast notification.

Comment: Are you testing this on the browser using `ionic serve`?

Comment: maybe try adding an error function to your promise.then or a catch after then

Comment: @Sampath No I am not testing it on Ionic Serve but an iPad running ios 10. The code functions properly on an Android device, and yes both the SKU's on the Playstore and App Store match. Hm...

Comment: @suraj My catch statement returns "[object Object]". I Updated my code on the forum post.

Comment: do       `message: JSON.stringify(err) + "",` in your catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, though I found the answer. You must request the product id from Apple before you can make the purchase. I also had to submit banking and tax information before Apple would validate any purchases.

Comment: Did the Ionic in app purchase end up working well for you? Are you using 1 or 2?